# Why is 都 placed after a verb in "什么时候还都可以"?

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-structure, phrase, word-order

I found this example:

> 你拿着用吧，什么时候还都可以。
>
> Nǐ ná zheyòng ba, shénme shíhòu huán dōu kěyǐ.
>
> You can have it as long as you want.

I am confused about the grammar structure behind 什么时候还都可以 (literally: any time you return it is ok). **How is it possible 都 occurs after the verb 还 (to return)?** Until now, I always saw 都 before any verb.

Comment: Make a pause here: ```(什么时候还) 都可以```, just like```(今天还 或者 明天还) 都可以```, take the first part as one subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence 什么时候还都可以

- the subject is 什么时候还 (the topic in topic-comment theory)
- the predicate is 都可以

可以 is 中心词 (key word or main verb), 都 is an adverb that modifies 可以.

Comment: Does 都 modify 可以? I thought instead modifies the time 什么时候 to mean *any time*. See also [Can an 'adverb' modify 'nouns/pronouns'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76622/can-an-adverb-modify-nouns-pronouns), even though that discussion is about English language, I think in Mandarin Chinese it has the same grammatical function.

Comment: @Puco4 The adverb 都 modifies the verb 可以. E. g. 我都可以. You'd think 都 modifies 我? Your quotation is not the same as your example in my opinion.

Comment: What does it mean 我都可以? Maybe here 都 means something else and complements the verb. However, usually I have seen 都 means *all*. So for example 我们都可以 means *we all can*. And in this case, I believe 都 modifies 我们 to mean *we all*. Also, from *C. Li, S. Thompson. Mandarin Chinese, A functional reference grammar*: "都 can refer only to a preceding noun phrase, and this noun phrase is generally the topic or the subject." I believe this is the same grammar function as in English when we say *almost everyone*, *almost* is an adverb that complements *everyone* (from the previous link).

Comment: @Puco4 我都可以 means I'm fine with either way.  Your sentence could insert a subject(not necessarily) 什么时候还我都可以.

Comment: @Puco4 我们都可以 might have two meanings according to context, "we all can" and "we are fine with either(or any) way".

Comment: But then, I believe 都 makes reference (and complements) another omitted noun (the possible ways), and not the verb.

Comment: @Puco4 Whatever makes sense to you...

Comment: @Puco4 都 is an adverb and syntactically goes with the verb. How you render any sentence in English is not relevant to understanding the structure of the source language. Easy test: does 我都 work alone? No. Does 都可以 work alone? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really like （你）还

Maybe this helps a little:

你什么时候把车还给我，都可以。我今天不需要用车。
You can return my car anytime. I don't need it today.

你随时可以把车还给我。我今天不需要用车。
You can return my car any time. I don't need it today.

你什么时候回来 （回家、回宾馆）， 都可以。
You can come back (come home, come back to the hotel) anytime.